# If $a-b=3,\ a+b+x=2,$ then the value of $(a-b)[x^3+3(a+b)x^2+3x(a+b)^2+(a+b)^3]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **Question**: If $a-b=3,\ a+b+x=2,$ then the value of $\left(a-b\right)\left[x^3+3\left(a+b\right)x^2+3x\left(a+b\right)^2+\left(a+b\right)^3\right]$ is?

---

I tried $a+b=2-x$ and $(a-b)(a+b) =a^2 +b^2$ = $(3)(x-2)=3x-6$
then I noticed that $3(a+b)x^2$ is basically $3x-6(x^3)$ or $a^2-b^2(x^2)$.
I tried factoring a bit more but it was getting too long and unsolvable.
Any hints?

Comment: Are you aware of $$(p+q)^3=?$$

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: What comes in your mind when you see the sequence $1,3,3,1$?

Comment: It's Quadratic.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Calculate $((a+b)+x)^3$. Now plug in the numbers you were given.